# Image wont display from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

Hey below I tried to display my image, it may be from the way I referenced in the src. Any ideas hot to fix? Thanks

(I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' )

```
                    <td><?php echo <img src='"/images/thumbs/.$row['thumb']."';?></td>
```

Comment: I can add anything if needed

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner method:

```
<?php $foo = $row['thumb'];?>
<td><?php echo '<img src="/images/thumbs/'.$foo.'"';?></td>
```

Comment: Hey thanks but now I get this: parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'thumb' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: No luck, it highlights below

Comment: @diz Sorry. This works.

Answer (score 0):

more ways... just keep attention on " and ' orders

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="/images/thumbs/'.$row['thumb'].'"';?></td>
```

you may also use:

```
<td><?php echo "<img src=\"/images/thumbs/{$row['thumb']}\"";?></td>
```

hope to be usefull

Comment: Tysm it works thats great